# error in implementing the geocoder

Tags: android, format, location

I'm trying to implement a Geocoder in a class this way:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);    
List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        (double)(coord.getLat()), (double)(coord.getLon()), 1);
if (list != null && list.size()>0 ) {
    Address address=list.get(0);
    String result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
}
```

The latitude and longitude that I pass to the  getLocationFrom() is integer in this form:

2365818 48930308 in the getFromLocation() I cast it to double .

Anyway my app blocks at this line:

```
 List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
     (double)(coord.getLat()), (double)(coord.getLon()), 1);
```

throwing the following:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: latitude == 2365818.0
 at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:114)
 at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:124)
```

at com.Server_1.ClientThread_special.run(ClientThread_special.java:70)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

Line 70 in ClientThread_special means this line:

```
List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

getFormLocation does not take lat below -90 or over 90. Long might be -180 to 180. Those are angle-degrees on the globe and your values are way to high.

See [Geocoder Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29)

Try to divide the values by 100000 to convert them to proper double-values.

**UPDATE:**

I might have been wrong regarding the amount you have to devide by. Try 1000000 (1M) aswell

Comment: But how could I transform this data:2365818

48930308 in degrees?Or what is the point...cause I don't get it....They should be in that interval....but is there any corespondence between my data those interval?

Comment: Just devide your data by 100000. You have integer-stored fixed point data. That are degress but multiplied by 100000 so they can be stored in an integer and are easier to display.

Comment: Where do you get your values from btw?

Comment: from a KML file loaded into DDMS,after that I sent them through a socket...is a long way...But now it gives me the following exception...

Comment: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server I assume it comes from google which seems to be unavailable...cause my maps aren't displayed as well:P

Comment: Well only my longitude I multiplied it with(1e-6) and latitude with (1e-5)....I know I should both of them multiply with (1e-6)

Comment: Do you have internet-access with the device/emulator? Have you tried displaying the map without doing your lookup?

Comment: I have internet acces...for sure...and the maps won't work even if I give up look up...and I have the right permissions in the manifest file...I can send u the whole code if u want too:D.....And I have a question for u!!Are u good with autocompletes in android?

Comment: Dou you get any error while displaying the maps? Well what does 'good' mean? :) What kind of autocomplete? Dou want to load remote-data over the web or local data for autocompletion?

Comment: No,my maps work usually and I get no error...Well,I have an autocomplete which does a query in a database.So,when I start typing in the autocomplete there are displayed two columns from my database(I built it that way to have two columns displayed,but the fltering is done only by one column)...Now when I chose one entry from the autocomplete I wanna to get returned other information from the DB related to that entry

Comment: Let's say that one row from my DB looks like: _id route data user_id.In my autocomplete when I start typing I get displayed only route and data...but when clicking it I want to know it's user_id from the Db which I use it for a further query in the DB...

Comment: You should create another question for that. Off-topic discussions are not too welcome here :)

Comment: I'm sure it's not very hard but I'm newish to this so I get stucked in this part ....I posted the question here several times but no one answered and it also got deleted cause I was asking the same thing too many times

Comment: Keep a map in the Backround where you put the visible text as key and the user_id as value.

Comment: I don't really know what that means:-S...sorry...a map and an autocomplete:-S

Comment: Ok create a HashMap wherever you have yout autocomplete-code. Then when you query the db for autocomplete-content, store the result in the HashMap. Use the visible text as key and the user_id as value.

Comment: Better I'll post another question and also put the link in here...and u can see then if u can help me or not..Thx;)